Optimize combination of resources to achieve multiple objectives
I have a bunch of resources that each yield a combination of outputs, and I’m trying to find the optimal amount of each resource to achieve a minimum amount of each output.
Simplified Details:

Resource $1$ yields $50x$ and $20y$
Resource $2$ yields $5y$ and $200z$
… etc

I want to find the optimal combination of resources to yield at least $400x, 500y$, and $800z$
Since these are resources, all amounts have to be $\ge 0$ of course
The actual problem has ~$50$ resources and ~$30$ unique outputs
I’m looking for a few search terms to get me started. I will be programming this in Python.
Things I tried already:

Scipy fsolve - didn’t find a solution
Scipy least_squares - gave $0$ for all resources, tried different initial guesses, no success
Long-form iterative solution, starting with outputs that can only be obtained from one resource. That solution broke down when I was left with ~$15$ resources and ~$10$ outputs. At that point, it started picking non-optimal options


You say 'Resource 1 yields 50x and 20y'. Does that mean $50x+20y$? I point this out because your problem is skipping a lot of detail. No one but you know what this problem is about, no one knows your maths level  and no one knows if by 50x and 20y you really mean $50x+20y$

Sure, I can give some more detail. I thought abstracting the problem was more helpful. I know basic optimization from an old class, and I work in machine learning, so not a beginner, but not a mathematician. To answer your first clarification question: Yes. In this case resource 1 is an ore, and when I reprocess it, I get 50 of mineral x and 20 of mineral y per unit of the resource, I'm using x and y to refer to unique outputs (minerals). Resource 2 refines to a bit of mineral y, but mostly z, etc... The optimal solution I'm thinking about would have the cost: min(sum units of all ores)

We should first focus on problem formulation before looking for solvers, otherwise, we can't pass the problem to the solver.
Rather than multiple objective, treat them as demand constraints that you have to meet.
Assuming you have $m$ unique resources. To obtain each unit of resource $i$, you have to pay $c_i$. If each resource is worth the same, then you can set all the $c_i=1$.
Let $x_i$ be the amount of resource $i$ to be acquired.
Then you want to minimize $\sum_{i=1}^m c_ix_i$
subject to $x \ge 0$ and for each output $j$, let say you have a minimum requirement of at least having $d_j$ of it.
Then we have constraints:
$$\sum_j^mA_{ij}x_j \ge d_i.$$
where $A_{ij}$ is the amount of output $i$ that will be produced for each unit of  resource $j$.
Whether $x_i$ must take integer value would depends on your context.
Lookout for terms such as integer programming or linear programming.

Thank you! linear programming was the solution. And thanks for also including how you would formulate the problem. I created a simplified version quickly to test it out in python, and it worked. The only modification I made was flip the rows/columns in  $A$ making columns $x_i$ coefficients for the constraints and rows outputs $j$
